# How to Convert Json Array to Single JSON object without using T object in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, dictionary, object

I am looking for a one-liner that transforms the Json array [{},{}] into object => [{}].

I have the following serialized JSON string,

```
 [
  {
    "Address": "Adresse"
  },
  {
    "AddressDetails": "Détails de l'adresse"
  },
  {
    "BackToLoginPage": "Retour à la page de connexion"
  }
]
```

Now I want to convert this into the following format without using one type or model object because the data is dynamic and it's going to contain 1000 number of fields so, I can not create a model type object with dynamic properties. So is there any idea to convert it into the one single JSON object/string?. It looks simple, but I couldn't convert it.

```
[
    "Address": "Adresse",      
    "AddressDetails": "Détails de l'adresse",      
    "BackToLoginPage": "Retour à la page de connexion"
]
```

Comment: Your last example is not valid JSON =)

Comment: Is this one line enough? `result = Regex.Replace(json,@"},|{|}","")`, though I would not recommend it. Also I would not recommend asking for one line answers , or writing questions without attempting something

Answer (score 2):

Newtonsoft.Json.Linq can parse/process JSON without model (JObject/JArray).
Here is one liner:

```
var mergedJson = new JObject(JArray.Parse(json).OfType<JObject>().SelectMany(o => o.Properties()).GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(grp => grp.First())).ToString();
```